# How to upload a WordPress website from localhost to a actual website URL using FTP?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hosting

I want to upload my wordpress website from localhost to my actual website.

> What should I do so that the website can access the MySQL db on the
>   remote server as it is on localhost? I do not have access to the
>   remote server, its mysql userid and passwd.

Secondly,

> I am also unable to send emails from localhost through my website,
>   when a user registers and waits to receive an account activation link. How can
>   I configure this on localhost and the remote server separately?

In the future, I would like to make changes locally and then upload to the real URL. How can I do this?

My localhost uses:

- FileZilla
- PHP 5.3
- MySQL 5
- WordPress 3.4.1
- phpMyAdmin

on Windows

Thanks

Comment: Use google before posting here.
To upload site on actual server use FileZilla - You need to know ftp address, username and password.
To configure database search in wordpress helps or look for config file in Your wordpress site. To make changes locally, edit local files, to update them to server, upload changed files.

Comment: I tried it, got a solution from a website but it isn't working. I have described the problem in another comment.

Comment: I'd say the [wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) are a better place to search for an answer to such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to copy your database structure over to your website host, if you export your database using phpmyadmin then reimport it on your host you will then need to replace localhost with your URL in the **wp_options** table, look for siteurl and home fields.

Once you have your database copied over copy your website files over then you will then need to edit your wp-config.php file to point to the new database.

Comment: I have done a few steps, correct me if I am wrong: 1. I exported my local database to a .sql file. 2. Replaced localhost with URL. 3. Imported the .sql file to the new db. 4. Now I see the old and new database in the MySQL installed on my PC. 5. I change the wp-config file with new db name, username and password of the db on my PC ie root user. 6. I upload the wordpress contents to the remote server but when I access the URL I get "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request." What to do now?

Comment: Also, does the .sql file need to uploaded with the wordpress folder contents?

Comment: You need to import the SQL file to your database on your webspace.

Comment: Can u tell me how? I do not have access to the remote database, I just have username and passwd for ftp.

Comment: You will need to speak to your hosting providers to get access information to the mySQL database if you do not have it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the wp-config.php and replace localhost with your website path in your database.

```
Like: http://localhost/wordpress

with

http://www.abc.com
```